# jQuery Accordion add arrow only if has child

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to add arrow to accordion main title link if it has child item else it will be a link itself to navigate the url.

I am following this tutorials http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_vertical_accordion_menu_using_cookies.htm

Code is as below

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http:actualurl">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http:actualurl">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using jQuery no conflict for Wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var checkCookie = jQuery.cookie("nav-item");

    if (checkCookie != "") {

        jQuery('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').addClass('active').next().show();

    }
    jQuery('#nav > li > a').click(function(){

        var navIndex = jQuery('#nav > li > a').index(this);

        jQuery.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
        jQuery('#nav li ul').slideUp();

        if (jQuery(this).next().is(":visible")){

            jQuery(this).next().slideUp();

        } else {

            jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();

        }

        jQuery('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your ready function

```
jQuery('#nav > li').each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).find('ul').length > 0)
    {
        //item has children; do whatever you want
        jQuery(this).prepend('<img src="path/to/iamge.png" />');
    }

});
```

Here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/qPfhG/4/

Comment: I have modified the code but not showing image. I am not sure I did right or wrong. Can you please check my modified question with your code.

Comment: dude, change the `src="path/to/iamge.png"`

Comment: Extremely sorry.. Its my mistake I just realized that. I did and works fine but one question if I want to add as a class for that li how can I do that? Also if I want to change that class on toggle like if i will add arrow but when its open it will pointed down and in close pointed side

Comment: To add a class to the `li` element instead of `jQuery(this).prepend('<img src="path/to/iamge.png" />')` use `jQuery(this).prepend('<img src="path/to/iamge.png" />').addClass('whatever')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I wanted to change class on #nav > li > a tag and this was adding on #nav > li. but I have changed code from `jQuery(this) to jQuery('#nav > li > a').addClass('class');` hope this wont make any issue

Comment: oh wow this code is applying class to all anchor tag not only which has child :(